# Is there a monotone function that is not differentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples, monotone-functions

One of the most strange things that I learned in Real Analysis is a function that is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but that is not differentiable everywhere.

I wonder how to prove that no monotone  function on $(a,b)$ can be not differentiable everywhere.

> Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let  $f:I \to \mathbb{R} $ be monotone on $I$. Then the
> set of points $D \subseteq I$ at which $f$ is discontinuous is a countable set.

any  monotone  function function is almost continuous everywhere and so there is no need to assume continuity

I couldn't prove or disprove that claim but my intuition was: If a monotone function is not differentiable at $x$ then there must be some Jump i.e $\lim\limits_{x\to c^-}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x\to c^+}f(x)\ne0$ so there must be uncountable many  Jumps and uncountable series of positive numbers must diverge (I couldn't find a **rigorous** proof for these two claims) so that mean $f(x)$ don't exist.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then the two limits in your last paragraph should both be $f(c)$, no?

Comment: For some much stronger and sharper results in this area, see [this 4 November 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/8vp1XK0-KNg/m/UOmRLJmd0xsJ) and [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1643616/13130). Regarding the result in Zahorski's 1946 paper that the previously mentioned MSE answer discusses, see also [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2747372/13130).